# redirect keypress from textbox to listview in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I am on a textbox if I press page down, I'd like to send page down to a list view.

Is there a way to pass this keypress along to the list view?  Or do I have to programmatically try to implement page down by moving down N rows or something like that?

If I were to explain it in terms of keypresses.

1. Focus is on the textbox.

( If I pressed pagedown now, this is what I would want to happen)

3. Focus goes to list view.
4. Press page down.
5. Focus back to textbox.

I'm just wondering if there is a way I can "pass" the keypress on to the listview control without actually doing all of that with keypresses, changing focus, etc.

Comment: What you mean by `send page down to a list view`? You mean, putting focus to listview?

Comment: I want it to be like I pressed page down on the listview.  So the selection would move down and list could possibly scroll.  But I want this to happen when I press page down and the focus is on a textbox.  The focus would remain in the textbox.

Comment: oohh!! that's a buggy behavior you are trying to inject.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to get, is something like this?

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode) {
        case Keys.PageDown:
            this.ListView1.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("{pgdn}");
            break;
    }
}

private void ListView1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode) {
        case Keys.PageDown:
            this.TextBox1.Focus();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Editing:**

Another way, without changing focus without using sendkeys is:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode) {
        case Keys.PageDown:
            this.LVW_PGDN();
            break;
    }
}

private void LVW_PGDN()
{
    int top = this.ListView1.TopItem.Index;
    int i;

    for (i = top; i < this.ListView1.Items.Count; i++) {
        this.ListView1.EnsureVisible(i);
        if (top < this.ListView1.TopItem.Index) {
            break;
        }
    }

    this.ListView1.TopItem = this.ListView1.Items(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: That is the right idea... but I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger the event without using sendkeys.  If I am in the list view and I press page down or page up I don't want to put the focus back to the textbox.

Comment: Ok! I understand. Then I will set a code that you can use instead of SendKeys without change of focus.